# Make table width fixed with Bootstrap table-condensed class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[Once I've solved this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028870/making-toggling-element-containing-table-stop-changing-column-widths), but now I am facing the problem that if I remove the table table-condensed classes, everything works fine. But I do really need the job that these classes do, and want to achieve fixed first column width WITHOUT removing table table-condensed.

```
<table class="table zeon zeon-row-hover table-condensed zeon-draggable zeon-with-edit-pencil">
  <thead>
    <th class='fixed-narrow-column'></th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- If there are any initiated tasks at all -->
    <tr>
      <td class='zeon-edit-pencil-column-pop-up fixed-narrow-column'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil zeon-edit-pencil'></span>
      </td>
      <td class='fixed-narrow-column'>A</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='zeon-edit-pencil-column-pop-up fixed-narrow-column'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil zeon-edit-pencil'></span>
      </td>
      <td class='fixed-narrow-column'>A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

AND I WANT THE 1st COLUMN TO BE NARROW !!!!
I expect that table table-condensed make the table stretch out by the entire space
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lmmwxzo/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your css :

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j49scz8/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qvbycfkw/

Comment: Can you please have a look at this jsFiddle. I've copied the original table from my app. The columns are fixed, much much wider than needed ((

Comment: Looks like all rows are equally distributed

Comment: Check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/eb5s0wgz/ . Now the table width is fixed, you can give separate widths  to each column to fit your need. I added a class for 1st column. The same as in your example.

Comment: I am about to go crazy. It works, but I can't figure out why !

Comment: because of `table-layout: fixed;`. Now the layout of table is fixed.